# Async.js series and node-mysql query's cant get rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-mysql, async.js

I am currently trying to run a set of MySQL query's in order using async.js series control flow function. But I keep receiving the following error:

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

I have tested the query's in seperate functions outside the async.series and they are fine and give me back the data, the only reason I can think for the error is due to the async nature it doesn't have the data at that time hence the error E.G when I log the rows I get:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

Below is the Async function:

```
 function SQLuserDataAsync() {
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        async.series([
                function (callback) {
                    connection.query('SELECT status FROM users WHERE name= ?;',
                        [userval],
                        function (err, rows) {
                        if (rows[0]['status']) {
                            console.log("Account Status: " + accountval);
                        } else {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        callback(null, 'one');
                    });
                },
                function (callback) {
                    connection.query('SELECT account_type FROM settings_tbl WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM users WHERE name= ?);',
                        [userval],
                        function (err, rows) {
                        if (rows[0]['account_type']) {
                            var acctype = rows[0]['account_type'];
                            console.log("Account Type: " + acctype);
                        } else {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        callback(null, 'two');
                    });
                },
                function (callback) {
                    connection.query('SELECT type FROM settings_tbl WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM users WHERE name= ?);',
                        [userval],
                        function (err, rows) {
                        if (rows[0]['type']) {
                            var type = rows[0]['type'];
                            console.log("Type: " + type);
                        } else {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        callback(null, 'three');
                    });
                }
            ]);
        connection.release();
    });
}
```

Any suggestions as the reason for the error or what am doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try to console the rows? maybe it doesn't have result that leads to that error

Comment: I can try that now, I believe that is the reason for the error but there is data there it seems its executing before the query has run if I was to take a guess.

Comment: I think not because you are in callback function

Comment: maybe it is wrap is dataValues?

Comment: The rows are empty, but if I run the query in a separate function outside the async series it works.

Comment: I think you should do a check for empty rows.. because if that is the case, then `rows[0]['status']` will through an error.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen In the question it says I said itcomes back empty when I run it using async series, but if I run the query in its separate function it gets the data fine, as I said before I believe the when I get `rows[0]['status']` the query hasn't run yet hence no data I think.

Comment: @Studento919 The callback function wouldn't run if the query hadn't been executed.

Comment: @Studento919 why  not to use it in .parallel ?  cuz I see in Your functions nothing special that want serial calls.

Comment: @num8er no its nothing special, am testing to see of works in order as I will need to execute a specific order of query's in the future, not that familiar with async.js

Comment: @Studento919 take a look at async's docs, there are necessary examples,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the main callback function to the [`async.series`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.series) function.

```
function SQLuserDataAsync() {
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        async.series([
                function (callback) {
                    // YOUR CODE
                },
                function (callback) {
                    // YOUR CODE
                },
                function (callback) {
                    // YOUR CODE
                }
            ], function(error, results) { // <--- this is the main callback
                connection.release();
            });
    });
}
```

You should call `connection.release()` inside the main callback, otherwise, the MySQL connection will be released/terminated before the queries are executed (due to the asynchronous nature the code).

Comment: Discovered thats not the problem it seems it cant get `[userval]` meaning its null hence no rows.... even tho its a global.

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `userval`?

Comment: I set it via a socket.on and set it as a global variable here.`socket.on('sqluser', function (userval) {
  users = socket.id;
  userval = userval;
  SQLuserDataAsync(userval);
 });`

Comment: Maybe the event is not getting triggered. Or, the statement `userval = userval;` is not assigning the value of local `userval` to the global `userval`. Hence it is remaining as null.

Comment: The event triggers the function, the expected value is there when the function is called I logged it just before it starts the async.series

Comment: You are passing `userval` as an argument to `SQLuserDataAsync` but in that function you are not accepting any parameter.

Comment: No, it wasnt that it seems there was an issue with the first query, I copied and used your answer as a template and it now works as expected, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if there is a user with defined in `userval` name it will work.

But let's simplify our code:

```
function SQLuserDataAsync(userval) {

    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        async.waterfall([

                // getting user
                function (next) {
                    connection.query(
                        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1',
                        [userval],
                        function (err, result) {
                          next(err, result[0]); // passing user to next function
                        });
                },

                // getting settings of user, maybe user_id (not id) in query below
                function (user, next) {
                    connection.query(
                        'SELECT * FROM settings_tbl WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1',
                        [user.id],
                        function (err, result) {
                          next(err, user, result[0]);
                        });
                },

                // handling both user and settings
                function (user, settings, next) {
                  console.log('User: ', user);
                  console.log('Settings: ', settings);
                  connection.release();
                }
            ]);
    });
}

SQLuserDataAsync('someone');
```